# two active sheets in google sheets update error based on cell comparison

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, cell

I'm trying to get this code working but I know I'm missing something. what the code should do is: to find a specific text from another cell using another sheet reference, so there are two sheets in the google sheet below:'BSR DATA' and 'ENTRY FORM'. from ENTRY FORM,cell g6 will compare its data to the first column of BSR DATA and if it meets the criteria, it will update the specific row of the array/cell reference with "new value".

link to google sheets:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kBuczydffPFBEfy2oegC1WsKXMjSxbGNRzWLCKurOMs/edit?usp=drivesdk

```
function UpdateBSRSpecial()
{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var testForm = ss.getSheetByName("ENTRY FORM");
    var testTable = ss.getSheetByName("BSR DATA");
    var testFormValue = testForm.getRange("G6").getValue();
    var rangeData = testTable.getDataRange();
    var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
    var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
  for(var i=0;i>lastRow;i++){
     var dataID = testForm.getRange(i,1).getValue();
     if(testFormValue == dataID)
    {
        testTable.getRange(i,6).setValue("new value");
    };
  };
};
```

Comment: try `testFormValue == dataID` or even `testFormValue === dataID`. = is used to assign a value, but equivalence requires "==" and strict equivalence  requires "==="

Comment: what if text is being compared. Itried that but it update all rows

Comment: "but it update all rows..." This is NOT the issue that the raised in your question. - it is a different issue altogether. It is updating every row because you are looping with this `for(var i=0;i>lastRow;i++){`. Let's start over: Would you please re-read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question to explain **exactly** what you are trying to do. Please also share a copy of your spreadsheet (without private or confidential information) and including an example of a successful outcome.

Answer (score 0):

The existing script is updating all rows because it loops with `for(var i=0;i>lastRow;i++){`. The following script demonstrates the process to search for a discrete term.

I am not going to deal with the updating of the "new value" since that is not clear from the question.

**Aspects to note**

- the script gets all the data on BSR - `var bsrdata = bsr.getRange(1,1,bsrLR,bstLC).getValues();`. This can be used later when updating values.
- using the Javascript [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method, Column A is extracted as a separate array for the search - `var bsrColA = bsrdata.map(function(e){return e[0];});//[[e],[e],[e]]=>[e,e,e]`
- the search is conducted using the Javascript [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method. Note: if a match is found, the method returns the index number of the search term within the array; if no match is found, the method returns "-1".
- the script tests to see if the search was successful: `if (result !=-1){`
- `indexOf` returns a zero-based index, therefore the actual row number is the index plus one: `var row = result+1;`

---

```
function so5866895401() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formsheetname = "ENTRY FORM";
  var form = ss.getSheetByName(formsheetname);
  var bsrname = "BSR DATA";
  var bsr = ss.getSheetByName(bsrname);

  // get input cell on form
  var searchterm = form.getRange("G6").getValue();
  // Logger.log(searchterm);// DEBUG

  //get data from BSR
  var bsrLR = bsr.getLastRow();
  var bstLC = bsr.getLastColumn();
  var bsrdata = bsr.getRange(1,1,bsrLR,bstLC).getValues();

  // get column A of BSR
  var bsrColA = bsrdata.map(function(e){return e[0];});//[[e],[e],[e]]=>[e,e,e]
  // Logger.log(bsrColA);// DEBUG

  // search for the searchterm in ColumnA of BSR
  var result = bsrColA.indexOf(searchterm); // zero-based
  if (result !=-1){
    var row = result+1;
    Logger.log("result = "+result+", row = "+row);
  }
}
```